# Android N Nougat 7.0 How to use FileProvider method without adding Android Support library to project

Tags: android, android-studio

Due to changes in ANDROID 7
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes?hl=en

"Passing file:// URIs outside the package domain may leave the receiver with an unaccessible path. Therefore, attempts to pass a file:// URI trigger a FileUriExposedException. The recommended way to share the content of a private file is using the FileProvider."

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider?hl=en

I'd like to know how can I use "built-in" methods in Android 7 to use the way/method that support library's FileProvider does under the hood without actually adding the support library to project.

Would that be possible? I know the support library is supposed to provide backward compatibility, though not sure how well that works since using the FileProvider on some old Android versions does NOT work, but the old method works. So then one is better off detecting Android version, if/else.

Anyway, I'm curious if anyone has a solution that works on Android 7> that doesn't use Android Support v4 library or the newer AndroidX jetpack etc.

Comment: `FileProvider` is a relatively simple `ContentProvider`. You could just copy the class: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/core/core/src/main/java/androidx/core/content/FileProvider.java. You don't really need the `androidx.annotation`s, so you can remove those and their imports. The only other thing I see off-hand is `ResourcesCompat.ID_NULL`, and you could replace that with your own constant.

Comment: `FileProvider` works on **every** API 14+ device (the `minSdkVersion` of AndroidX) or every API 4+ device (the `minSdkVersion` of the original Support Library version). You should absolutely just it.

Comment: @ ian when your apk is minsdk 9 not 14+ and apk size is 1.5mb and support library etc makes it over 2MB, means support library adds another 1/3rd of size of apk @mike-m Thanks! I'll look into that.